# Kafka Advertised Listener when running in Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

As a beginner in docker and kafka world,
I tried to connect kafka which is running in docker container on bridge network in my local machine, now from my local i want to connect kafka, i gone through this [link](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/)

below is the snapshot of docker compose from above link

```
kafka0:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.2.1"
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '29094:29094'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      […]
      # For more details see See https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092,LISTENER_FRED://kafka0:9092,LISTENER_ALICE://kafka0:29094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092,LISTENER_FRED://localhost:9092,LISTENER_ALICE://never-gonna-give-you-up:29094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_BOB:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_FRED:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_ALICE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_BOB
[…]
```

if using this configuration i can connect to kafka from my local-machine

```
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 \
> -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1002: localhost:9092/1002):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1002 at localhost:9092
```

but i do not understand how it is working,

my understanding is that when client wants to connect to kafka it need to give broker address `KAFKA_LISTENERS` in this case, after connecting client will get metadata having info of actual ip of brokers which is provided in `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`

now my doubt is: according to config in docker compose we are using FRED listener, if we want to connect kafka from local machine, but in `KAFKA_LISTENERS` we have given `LISTENER_FRED://kafka0:9092` which is not accessible from local so how is this working and as soon as i changed it to `LISTENER_FRED://localhost:9092`
got error

```
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -C -t beats
% ERROR: Failed to query metadata for topic beats: Local: Timed out
```

but works if set `LISTENER_FRED://kafka0:9092` in `KAFKA_LISTENERS`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This might help: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Answer (score 0):

When you call `localhost:9092` it is getting hit `kafka0` docker instance. Then it is working as `kafka0:9092` for docker environment. So if you configured docker kafka listener like `localhost:9092`, it is not getting hit because there is no mapping for `docker localhost` with your `localhost`

Comment: thanks @nipuna for you help, but when using localhost:9092 and it return address kafka:9092, then how kafka client which is running on local will be able to connect kafka:9092, as local machine does not know about kafka:9092

Comment: That mapping happened when you do the port mapping